# REACT wait for useEffect to complete before rendering the UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect, react-component

```
interface MyValue {
    //interface declaration
}
    
export function MyComponent {   
    const [myvalue, setMyvalue] = useState<MyValue>()
    
    useEffect(() => {
       setMyvalue(passedData)
    }, [passedData])
    
    function getAutofocus() {
        // return true/false based on myvalue value
    }
        
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
             <input
                autofocus={getAutofocus()}
                ref={c => (this._input = c)}
             />
          </div>
         );
       }
    }
 }
```

**passedData** is passed as a prop from parent and this is populated in the parent via a server GET call, which takes some time to resolve.

PROBLEM - **getAutofocus()** rendered before **passedData** is properly loaded.

my requirement here is to wait until passedData is properly resolved before invoking the
**getAutofocus()** method.
If we can stop the rendering of the UI/ or the input field until **passedData** is completely resolved, that will allow **getAutofocus()** to properly execute.

what's the best way to do this? can react suspense be used here?

Comment: Side question.  Is it permissible to use hooks (useState, useEffect) like you are doing inside a class React component class?  That is, I thought hooks were only for single function ("pure") components.

Comment: changed the code to use a function instead of a class

Comment: That's still not how you implement a pure component.  Take out the `render()` declaration and just have the final statement be the return of the JSX element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like conditional rendering would be enough to get what you need:

```
    render() {
       // if myvalue is not populated yet, do not render anything
       return !myvalue ? null : (
          <div>
             <input
                autofocus={getAutofocus()}
                ref={c => (this._input = c)}
             />
          </div>
         );
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The proper way of doing this is with a ref

```
const MyCom = props => {

const inputRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(()=>{
  if (inputRef.current) {
     inputRef.current.focus();
}

},[inputRef]);

return (
          <div>
             <input
                ref={inputRef}
             />
          </div>
         );
}
```

Remove render method only class components have render

Comment: this was the answer for me as my component (my version of MyCom) was reusable and could be called in succession with different input refs. In this case, the solution provided by @CertainPerformance would not work. Because myValue would have a value, but the wrong one.